# fatal: remote error: Individual contributor agreement requires current contact information

Tags: android, git, submit

step by step under link

http://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html#upstream-projects

However,after `$repo upload` ,the follow error occur,

**fatal: remote error: Individual contributor agreement requires current contact information.**

I can see the following option under Group

CLA Accepted - Individual    Users who have accepted the Individual CLA

and the following option under Agreements

Verified    Individual   If you are going to be contributing code on your own, this is the one you want. You can sign this one online.

There are some usage info. image
[image: Agruments]
[image: Groups]

**something wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to signing the CLA you also need to enter your [contact information](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/settings/contact) in the settings. Note that it can take several minutes until the changes have been replicated to all servers and you're able to push.